# array type is not assignable

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to create two references to an array which could be refer to the same array. I tried the following:

```
extern int (&a)[];
extern int (&b)[];

int main()
{
    b = a; // error: array type 'int []' is not assignable
}
```

Is there a way to do that in c++?

Comment: You can't re-bind references. Could you be more clear on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: You could write `int a[5]; int (&b)[5] = a; int (&c)[5] = a;`

Comment: Why not use pointer in such case?

Comment: What is the context for this, perhaps a different approach would be better.

Comment: @Brian Why can't we rebind references? Because of the Standard?

Comment: @Brian I didn't try to rebind reference. I tried to bind two references to an array to the same object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things: first [arrays](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) cannot appear on the left hand of an assignment operator. cppreference probably takes its text directly from the standard, particularly:

§ 8.3.4

> <sup>5</sup> Objects of array types cannot be modified, see 3.10.

Also, like cppreference says, arrays are lvalues:

§ 3.10

> <sup>1</sup> Expressions are categorized according to the taxonomy in
>   Figure 1. — An lvalue (so called, historically, because lvalues could
>   appear on the left-hand side of an assignment expression) designates a
>   function or an object.

Although, the standard explicitly says that objects of array types cannot be modified, therefore concluding that arrays (which are objects) cannot appear on the left hand side of the assignment operator.

Secondly, while the compiler may not complain if you do this:

```
int a = 50, c = 42;
int& b = a;
b = c;
b = 80;
std::cout << a << " " << c; // 80 42
```

you will see that `c` remains unchanged. Please refer to the [parashift C++-faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/index.html).

[[8.5] How can you reseat a reference to make it refer to a different object?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/reseating-refs.html)

> No way.
>
> You can't separate the reference from the referent.
>
> Unlike a pointer, once a reference is bound to an object, it can *not*
>   be "reseated" to another object. The reference itself isn't an object
>   (it has no identity; taking the address of a reference gives you the
>   address of the referent; remember: the reference *is* its referent).

Comment: Your answer is clear, but _arrays cannot be appear on the left LHS of an assignment op_. Is there a normative reference to the current working draft?

Comment: @Dmitry Tried to provide the most relevant quotes I could find. See the edit.